# Excel File Created By EPPlus creating error while upload on google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, epplus

I'm Using EPPlus for creating excel files and this file is upload on google dirve using api. 
but suddenly google drive not support file or not upload file created by epplus . i did not understand what the problem . epplus creating open office format.

Comment: Could you provide code samples, error responses and Open Office sheets EPPlus is generating?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Take any Excel file generated by the EPPLus Sample solution (sample1.xlsx)
Then import them into Google Drive, you get the following error:
The spreadsheet you are trying to upload is invalid.
Tested on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: this error is occur because of epplus generates open office format and google drive does not support open office format..

Comment: google drive does support Office Open XML, which EPPLus is generating. But these documents curently cannot be opened by google drive or SkyDrive.